# using clientScripts in config with module

Tags: javascript, testing, module, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm curious what is required by a module in order to be used in the configuration in this way:

```
"clientScripts": { "module":"myModule" }
```

what does "myModule" need to do in order to be used in this way?  Does it need to set something in its package.json?  or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The module should be in the [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) format.
2. The module should be installed in your project, so `package.json` should contain it.
3. If your module depends on some other modules, so these other modules should be added on the page in the same manner before the dependent module.

Comment: are there any examples out there I can look at?  The docs have lodash but does that work? @alex-kamaev

Comment: Yes, it works. I recommend that you try it on your side.
Docs: [Inject Scripts into Tested Pages](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/inject-scripts-into-tested-pages.html#add-client-scripts-to-specific-tests)